# $n-$dimension integral

Tags: definite-integrals, integral-equations

Is there anyone could help me solve the following equation:

$$\int_0^t \int_0^{t-v_1} \cdots \int_0^{t-\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} v_i} \prod_{j=1}^k f(\sum_{i=1}^{j} v_i) dm(v_k) \cdots dm(v_2)dm(v_1)$$

You may safely assume $f(v), m(v)$ are nice functions here. I am only interested how to solve this kind of integral and what kind of m could enable us to achieve a nice result.

Comment: If $m$ is the Lebesgue measue it equals $(\int_0^t f(v) dv)^k$ by substitution and Fubini.

Comment: Yes, you are right. However, I am wondering what if m(v) is other measures, say$$m(v)=v^a$$, for $a \in (0,1]$